# Dask Distributed Client - ERROR - Failed to reconnect to scheduler after 10.00 seconds, closing client

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, dask, dask-ml

I am doing a very simple data transformation with `Dask_ML` and I am getting this error, I was wondering if anyone has encountered this. Looks like a system setting that can be modified?

```
df.head()

ReportDate_Time 2015-05-01  2015-06-01  2015-07-01  2015-08-01  2015-09-01  2015-10-01  2015-11-01  2015-12-01  2016-01-01  2016-02-01  ... 2017-04-01  2017-05-01  2017-06-01  2017-08-01  2017-09-01  2017-10-01  2017-11-01  2017-12-01  2018-01-01  2018-02-01
0   33.0    32.0    32.0    24.0    24.0    32.0    31.0    31.0    31.0    35.0    ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   670.0   978.0   1061.0  1048.0  525.0   936.0   804.0   1067.0  859.0   647.0   ... 407.0   457.0   517.0   388.0   345.0   428.0   688.0   1486.0  1090.0  0.0
2   132.0   130.0   127.0   137.0   92.0    96.0    112.0   124.0   126.0   112.0   ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
3   206.0   259.0   207.0   181.0   74.0    142.0   125.0   172.0   138.0   194.0   ... 188.0   211.0   239.0   179.0   159.0   197.0   318.0   315.0   189.0   190.0
4   290.0   311.0   401.0   381.0   138.0   315.0   275.0   407.0   408.0   419.0   ... 76.0    56.0    159.0   16.0    0.0 0.0 213.0   123.0   4.0 3.0
5 rows × 33 columns

from dask_ml.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df_pivot)

Gives Error:

CancelledError: 
distributed.client - ERROR - Failed to reconnect to scheduler after 10.00 seconds, closing client
distributed.utils - ERROR - 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 662, in log_errors
    yield
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1290, in _close
    await gen.with_timeout(timedelta(seconds=2), list(coroutines))
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
distributed.utils - ERROR - 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 662, in log_errors
    yield
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1019, in _reconnect
    await self._close()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 1290, in _close
    await gen.with_timeout(timedelta(seconds=2), list(coroutines))
concurrent.futures._base.CancelledError
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can configure timeouts in dask.distributed with the following:

```
distributed:
  comm:
    timeouts:
      tcp: 50s              # time before calling an unresponsive connection dead
```

or in the code:

```py
import dask
import distributed
dask.config.set({"distributed.comm.timeouts.tcp": "50s"})
```

Answer (score 2):

Code may have changed since @quasiben's answer.  According to the [client's constructor](https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/342b6a65e30082c45b4072b29217ab4525572894/distributed/client.py#L602), the config name is different.

The timeout can be set done explicitly:

```
Client(..., timeout="50s")
```

or in the configs ("connect" instead of "tcp")

```
import dask
import distributed
dask.config.set({"distributed.comm.timeouts.connect": "50s"})
```